# Application Error . UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, runtime-error

Am making an application in JavaFX, Wherein I am also using an RXTX-Serial communication.
Before starting the application, am getting an Application Error as below :

```
UnsatisfiedLinkError:
com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.MSystemProxyHandler.init()Z
```

A dialogue box appears everytime I start the application. It doesn't matter if select OK or Cancel or Close the window the application starts after that. And all functions seem to be working ok. But when it gives an another error anytime in between. The error is as described below :

```
Have no file for /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/netx.jar
Have no file for /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/plugin.jar
Have no file for /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/jfr.jar
```

Could you please tell me the meaning of this error or where I am making a mistake.
And ya.. I would like to add that the same application works fine in Windows 7. Right now am running it on Ubuntu 12.04LTS.

Comment: This is a pretty old message so you probably found your answer already.

I have the same problem, and I use the same platform.

I think that it's precisely becasue we are using the openjdk.
It's supposed to work with java-7-oracle.
I have it installed and it's the jvm I use for my deployment however at runtime it seems to be using openjdk. I made sure that default-java points to java-7-oracle too but that didn't help. Did you have any success yet?

Answer (score 0):

As commented.
The problem comes from using the default JDK.

To fix it, I did the following.
In Netbeans, go to Menu File > project properties ([project name]).
In the Project properties Window, go to the "Libraries" section.
At the very top, change "Java Platform" from "Default JavaFX Platform" to "JDK 7 Oracle".

Execute your application again. The error popup disappears.